# how to navigate from subview to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I want to navigate from subview to another view.i have written the code but it is navigating from this view.please help me in solving this problem.

```
NSLog(@"selected tag:%d",[sender tag]);
UserViewController *uViewController=[[UserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserViewController" bundle:nil];
uViewController.usersArray=self.usersArray;
uViewController.accessingIndex=[sender tag];
self.userViewController=uViewController;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.userViewController animated:YES];
[uViewController release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to show a view

```
[self presentModalViewController:uViewController animated:YES]
```

To close it use:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:yes]
```